# Django RegexValidator does not display message

Tags: python, django

Why the RegexValidator is not showing the message? It looks like I'm posting too much code...
Here is my views.py:

```
from polls.forms import ContactForm
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template import Context, Template, RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.loader import render_to_string, get_template

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")

 def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    # new logic!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email', '')
            phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number', '')
            content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            # Email the profile with the 
            # contact information

            message = render_to_string('contact_template.txt', {'contact_name': contact_name, 'contact_email': contact_email, 'phone_number': phone_number, 'form_content': content}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


            email = EmailMessage("New contact form submission", message, "annadrybulska@gmail.com" +'', ['annadrybulska@gmail.com'], headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email })
            email.send()

            return redirect('contact')

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form_class,})
```

here is my forms.py(where RegexValidator is causing me troubles!):

```
    from django import forms
    from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
    from django.core import validators
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

    #new form
    class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
        contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
        phone_number = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=9, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d+$', message='Nieprawidłowy numer telefonu.', code='invalid_number', inverse_match=None, flags=0
    )])
        content = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Imię:"
            self.fields['contact_email'].label = "E-mail:"
            self.fields['phone_number'].label = "Numer telefonu:"
            self.fields['content'].label = "Wiadomość:"
```

and my template.py:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Formularz kontaktowy</h1>
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Wyślij</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are *any* validation errors displayed, or just not this one? You should show more of the code: the rest of the form, the view, and the template.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, the email one is working but it is a built one, I'll add more code right away..thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

You're passing into template context `form_class` instead of `form` if your post request is `POST` and form is not valid. To solve the issue, change your last line of view to this three lines:

```
    else:
        form = form_class()

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form,})
```

It will create empty form if there is no post data and pass `form` instead of `form_class` to your template.